# YouTube Channel Reports API not giving metrics (views, likes...) for current day (using Targeted Queries)

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I'm using [channel_reports from YouTube analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports) to fetch metrics such as views, likes, etc, but I can't fetch data for the current day (I can tough, get data spanning from a few days back). Even if I watch, like a bunch of videos and subscribe to the channel I'm trying to fetch the data from, I don't see any data.

I'm using the following to get data:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

youtubeAnalytics = build(api_name, version, credentials=credentials) ### using Oauth token and all

startDate = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).date()
endDate = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=0)).date()

metric_names = ["likes", "dislikes", "views", "subscribersGained", "subscribersLost"]
youtubeAnalytics.reports().query(
    ids='channel==MINE',
    startDate=startDate.isoformat(),
    endDate=endDate.isoformat() ,
    metrics=",".join(metric_names ),
    dimensions="day"
).execute()
```

But with the `startDate` and `endDate` representing today and yesterday, the results are empty (even after viewing lots of videos, subscribing, liking with other accounts).

For past data though, it yields results.

Comment: Jus to make sure, can you print the values of `startDate` and `endDate`? - if the problem persists, consider also include this info in a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc)

Comment: Sure thing. but it's just the isoformatting of the day (I edited the post, cuz I think I missed the isoformat() there).
But it prints: 
(datetime.date(2023, 2, 22), datetime.date(2023, 2, 23))
that's for today